# Omitting rows in a calculated excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very simple worksheet with financial data. It has 13 columns and formulas in 6 of them. The first row is column headings. The second row is beginning balances and should not be included in the calculations for the remainder of the column. I simply cannot figure out how to maintain the formula(s) as rows are added to the columns. I tried creating a table and using calculated columns, but the formula over-rode row 2 beginning balances.

This seems like a very ordinary need yet I can't resolve it. I am fairly new to Excel so your answers need to not assume a great knowledge base. I'm learning as I go. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use the if function inside your formula in order to evaluate the contents of the cells you're concerned of?

Answer (score 1):

The order of things matters in this case. If you enter a starting balance first, then try to create a formula in the next row that needs to be applied to the rest of the table, you will not succeed.

Instead, create your table, create the formula for the balance column. Leave the first row after the labels blank for the time being. Add a few rows of data and confirm that the balance formula is applied to new rows and works as intended.

Now go back to the first row of data and manually overwrite the balance formula with the starting balance. This will keep the column formula intact and it will continue to be applied to new rows, while the first row has a static value.

Excel may display a green error triangle that shows the message "this cell is inconsistent with the column formula", but since that is exactly what you want to happen, you can click to ignore that message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A data table is expected to be homogenous, all the same data throughout. Including starting balances in there is going to throw it off.

Your best option may be to include the starting balances ABOVE the table, on a separate row on their own, or even in a separate worksheet, then refer to those cells with formulae in the data table.